# Android Calendar get event throws IOException 404 not found -- why?

Tags: android-calendar

I've been working on this for three days, and I'm out of ideas.
I've been through MANY stackOverflow questions and answers. None helped.
My calendar is setup successfully with this code:

```
com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport x = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory gF = new GsonFactory();
calendar = new Calendar.Builder(x, gF, credential)
    .setApplicationName(getString(R.string.app_name))
    .build();
```

I know the calendar service is okay because I can do many things with it, like insert an event.
But this rather simple code throws an IOException 404 not found:

```
Event event = calendar.events().get("primary", eventId).execute();
```

I know eventId is a String that ids an event that exists in the primary calendar.
Why does this code throw the exception? and how can I make it not throw it?

Comment: Does the event you are trying to fetch _actually_ live in the primary calendar? Or another calendar Id belonging to the user? Maybe try fetching a list of all available, and querying the event from those? [docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list)

Comment: The event definitely exists in the primary calendar; I created it there with: calendar.events().
                     insert("primary", event).setSupportsAttachments(true)
                     .execute();

Comment: I checked the programcreek codes several days ago. Various examples led me down various rabbit holes that didn't help. Wish they had! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found my own answer. I am getting the eventId from a query into the 
"content://com.android.calendar/events" database table.
It has 98 columns, and I thought "_id" is the event id.
It is not. It appears that column "_sync_id" is the event id.
Statement:

```
 calendar.events().get("primary", eventId).execute();
```

returns the correct Event object when eventId comes from column "_sync_id".
Maybe someone can confirm that "_sync_id" is truly the correct column to use.